# How to inherit a class with bunchs of partitional specialization interfaces

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Assume I have a class `A` and a template function `I<T>`.
I have a partial version `I<A>`.

Now, I need to **add some data members** to `A`. So I try to inherit `A` with a class `B`. However, function `I<T>` instead of `I<A>` will be executed now.

Any chance I can get the extended class `B` without losing interface `I<A>`?
I prefer to not modifying the functions `I` and class `A`, because they are really complicated actually and belong to third-party.

** Manually casting is not workable too, since `B&` will be cast to `A`.

**Edited:**

What i am really interested at is why **polymorphism** seems doesn't work fine with partitional specialization here? Is something wrong or just C++ behaves so?

**Example Code**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {};

class B: public A {};

template <typename T>
void print(T t) {
    cout << "base template method" << endl;
}

template <>
void print(A t) {
    cout << "partitional template method" << endl;
}

int main() {
    A a;
    print(a);       // partitional method
    B b;
    print(b)            // base method
    print<A>(b);        // partitional method
}
```

`I<A>(b)` works fine, but addtional `<A>` is also unacceptable for my case too. I need I(b) works fine.

Comment: You can't modify `I` nor `A`, but could you modify `I<A>` (or add an `I<B>`)?

Comment: Also I cannot contain class A as a data member of class B. Since there are lots of A.func() code in current project. In general, class B should behaves like class A, just some extra members.

Comment: @kennytm I really don't want that. I<A> actually refering quite a lot of functions, so it's hard to add I<B>. And I<A> belongs to third-party library. But That's what i plan to do if i get no more options.

Comment: If `I` has the `T` as parameter you can also overload it as `I(A)`. Overloads should be preferred over templates.

Comment: @MarkusZaczek yes but it requires copy and adjust all I<T>. it's quite a lot code in my case.

Comment: You can try to call `I<A>` directly (it should work if this template takes reference or pointer as param). PS Can you post some code to make it a little bit clear?

Comment: Check this [code](https://godbolt.org/g/wUAcfd). Did I understood your problem correctly?

Comment: @MichaelNastenko that's true. but `I<A>` was also used by the third-party code itself. So some error still exists. I will add some example code, thank you for advice

Comment: @MichaelNastenko exactly. the problem is that i cannot change all `I(a)` to `I<A>(a)` for all library codes. I hope polymorphsim could play the hero here.

Comment: @ZenWu That you should create template specialization for your type `B`. Like [here](https://godbolt.org/g/r1KwD4).

Comment: @MichaelNastenko so polymorphsim doesn't work here? I mean, create `I<B>` means manually force them to have same behavior. And like I mentioned, I don't want to add so many code.

Comment: @ZenWu It has nothing to do with polymorphism. And I don't see how it adds too much code - it just one function.

Comment: @ I mean by polymorphism that if an interface is specialized to A, then it should treat subclass B as A too, for default. Create one `I<B> ` is serveral lines maybe, but I have thousands of such functions to handle.

Comment: @ZenWu "thousands of such functions"? What kind of library is it? I'm pretty sure you exaggerate it a lot. I don't think it possible to help you more w/o real code.

Comment: @MichaelNastenko okay, you got me. I am using [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org). Its boosting graph operations module contains a graph_traits module to do specialization. That file has over 400 lines code. I don't want add a copy of it, escpeically it cannot handle other modules if there is.

Comment: @ZenWu I can't say it became clear now. I still don't understand what you are trying to do. What class do you extend? What functions do you want to use?

Comment: @ZenWu your terminology is off. `I<A>` is a **full specialisation** of the template function `I<>`. Inheritance is how c++ does **subtype polymorphism**, but it also does **structural polymorphism** with templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to have `B b; I(b);` result in the specialisation of `I` for `A` is to have a specialisation for `B` that calls it. You can however assign a `B` to an `A&` variable, and pass that to `I`, and that will use the `A` specialisation.

Template specialisation is only for exact matches of type [after deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction).

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {};

class B: public A {};

template <typename T>
void print(T& t) {
    cout << "base template method" << endl;
}

template <>
void print(A& t) {
    cout << "specialisation for A of template method" << endl;
}

template <>
void print(B& t) {
    cout << "specialisation for B of template method" << endl;
    print<A>(t);
}

int main() {
    A a;
    print(a);       // A specialisation used
    B b;
    print(b);       // B specialisation used, which calls A specialisation
    print<A>(b);    // A specialisation used
    A & ab = b;
    print(ab);      // A specialisation used
}
```